# How with bash to get from a path all but the first folder

Tags: bash

How with bash to get from a path all but the first folder ?

e.g.

from `'a/b/d/e'` to get `'b/d/e'`

for now I do that with pythonpy

```
$ pip install pythonpy
$ echo 'a/b/d/e' | py -x '"/".join(x.split("/")[1:])'
b/d/e
$
```

The #Cyrius solution work well::

```
$ x='a/b/d/e'
$ echo "${x#*/}"
b/d/e
$
```

but after reading [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion), the only related example with  `${parameter#...}` is::

```
${parameter#word}
${parameter##word}

  The word is expanded to produce a pattern just as in filename expansion (see 
  Filename Expansion). If the pattern matches the beginning of the expanded value
  of parameter, then the result of the expansion is the expanded value of
  parameter with the shortest matching pattern (the ‘#’ case) or the longest
  matching pattern (the ‘##’ case) deleted. If parameter is ‘@’ or ‘*’, the
  pattern removal operation is applied to each positional parameter in turn, and
  the expansion is the resultant list. If parameter is an array variable
  subscripted with ‘@’ or ‘*’, the pattern removal operation is applied to each
  member of the array in turn, and the expansion is the resultant list.
```

That did not help me much to understand what is made by  `"${x#*/}"`

Comment: `echo 'a/b/d/e' | cut -d / -f 2-`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

With bash and its [Parameter Expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bash.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion):

```
x='a/b/d/e'
echo "${x#*/}"
```

Output:

```
b/d/e
```